# Add a simple down arrow image to drop down menus

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I have a site where certain menu headings are drop down (css)

I want to add a small down facing arrow onto the certain menu headers that are able to drop down. Can anyone give me any ideas how to do so?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just use this character: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25bc/index.htm

```
&#9660;  - ▼
```

Comment: For up-pointing arrow: use ```&#9652;``` https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25b4/index.htm

Answer (score 10):

```
a:after{
    content: '';
    border: 4px solid transparent;
    border-top: 4px solid white;
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

I think this is the best way to do it, as you can adjust the border for the length and adjust the 'border-top' for the height, giving you full customization.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using bootstrap, you can do the following:

```
<span class="caret"></span>
```

This will insert a small down arrow wherever the span is placed.

Answer (score 0):

**If you've creating menu and, you want the arrow not fill black in the arrow try this code: (to: arrow not fill any color)**

```html
&nabla; - ∇
```

Comment: Interesting the [nabla symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nabla_symbol) has a named entity.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code to add the arrow, customize the height and widht and position for the arrow as per your need.

```
    li.has_child:after {  
        content: '';   
        position: absolute;   
        border: 7px solid transparent; 
        /* This will set the direction of the arrow.*/  
         border-top: 7px solid white; 
           top: 34px; 
        margin-left: 5px; 

  }
```